# Qué determina que se prenda y apague el led 1

Tags: assembly

soy totalmente novato en assembler y tengo que hacer un proyecto para la universidad, me pidieron que el código que voy a proporcionar a continuación, lo modifique para que se encienda otra led y apague otra led, en este código se enciende y se apaga el led 1,  el tema es que lo intento entender y no entiendo que es lo que determina que se encienda ese led y como lo puedo modificar para poder encender otro, el código es este:

```
;
; AssemblerApplication6.asm
;
; Created: 31/8/2021 15:27:54
; Author : Administrador
;
.include "./m328Pdef.inc"
.org 0x00 ;aca arranca el programa
; Replace with your application code
setup: ; configuro los puerto y pongo valores incinales
ldi r16,0b00111100; 
out DDRB,r16; configuro el puerto para para que los pines 5 al 2 sean salida
ldi r16, 0xFF;
out PORTB,r16;
start:
    ldi r16,0b00111100; 
    out PORTB,r16; prendo el pin 2 del puerto B. -
    rjmp start
```

Comment: El lenguaje ensamblador establece una relación 1:1 entre las instrucciones del lenguaje con las instrucciones del procesador. No podemos ayudarte si no sabemos cuál es el conjunto de instrucciones con el que funciona tu procesador.

Comment: Mi procesador es un ATmega328P y los leds D1 D2 D3 D4 están conectados en los Pines del 2 al 5 del puerto B, eso es suficiente para que me puedas ayudar? , mi idea es que quiero prender otro led que no sea el D1, por ejemplo no sé, el D2

Comment: [según las defs](https://github.com/DarkSector/AVR/blob/master/asm/include/m328Pdef.inc) sería algo como setear el pin correspondiente a 1 en un registro general `ldi  r16,(1<<PINB2)` ... `ldi  r16,(1<<PINB5)`  luego enviarlo `out  PORTB,r16` ( algún tipo de loop condicional o delay para ir cambiando pines )

Comment: Solo sé assembler para PC. Puedes encontrar información [aquí](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-E06F3258-483F-4A7B-B1F8-69933E029363-en-US-2/index.html?GUID-AAE74D1B-2E66-4C00-87F3-E62598068707).